# Question regarding epsilon delta proofs

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

[image]

The specific expression envolving epsilon on the third line of the proof seems like it came from hindsight. 
however, my question is, why does the end of the proof have to show that the difference is less than exactly epsilon? Wouldn't it have the same implications if i showed that it was less than 3$\epsilon$+1 or any random term evolving epsilon? Is it just for formality?

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer: $3\varepsilon+1$ wouldn't be good, since it is not "small". But $3 \varepsilon$ would be fine, and moregenerally any fixed positive multiple of $\varepsilon$.

The choice of $\varepsilon / (2|b|+1)$ was made for convenience.

Comment: Ahh yes I see. But to finalise, the only reason we choose to end the proof by having epsilon, is because in the beginning we wanted to show that "for some N there is an epsilon...". However, other than that, the implications of showing the difference is less than 3$\epsilon/(3\epsilon$+1) would be the same as $\epsilon$ in saying something converges.

Comment: A very gross statement is that you must end up with a quantity that tends to zero as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: To be precis, the $\epsilon-\delta$ def does not works becuase $\epsilon$ is "small" ... but it is stated for **all** $\epsilon$ (and thus also for the "small" ones).

Answer (score 0):

if you can get that the term is less than $p(\epsilon)$ with $p$ a polynomial such that $p(0)=0$ that is enough or even
$$
p(\epsilon^a)
$$
for some $a>0$ is enough.

I find proofs where they pick the multiples of $\epsilon$ at the beginning to make it work a bit artificial.

(see my book Proof Patterns for more discussion)

Comment: Thanks. That's essentially what I wanted to ask, whether or not the final difference can be less than some polynomial of epsilon.